# Is adding too many stubbed methods a reason for adding special constructor just for tests? (over mocking)

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I want to add unit tests for a method in class `ClassToBeTested.execute()`. `ClassToBeTested` is a business model class received from REST api. To call that method I have to:

- create a class `AAAclass` (which must have 2 inner class mocked and stub 7 methods to put call the method I want to test)
- put that mocked `AAAclass` in `ClassToBeTested`; `ClassToBeTested` depends on `AAAclass`

The `AAAclass` looks like:

```
    public class AAAclass {
        @SerializedName("BBBclass")
        private BBBclass BBBclass;

        public class BBBclass {
            @SerializedName("CCCclass")
            private CCCclass ccc;

            public DDDclass getDDD() {
                if (ccc != null) {
                    return ccc.getDDD();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        private class CCCclass {
            @SerializedName("DDDclass")
            private DDDclass ddd;

            public DDDclass getDDD() {
                return ddd;
            }
        }

        public class DDDclass {
        }
    }
```

I got the feeling that I'm doing sth wrong and it seems to be [over mocking](https://mestachs.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/mockito-best-practices/):

> Don’t mock your model: Easier to read and you will may be add convenient constructor/factory methods to your production or test codebase.

So should I really add a special constructor just to use it in unit testing?

Comment: We really can't say without context - we have absolutely *no* information about what these classes are for. Mock services; don't mock data, generally.

Comment: I'll update the question then if it's important.

Comment: +1 Need more information. I want to point you to the magic of _dependency injection_ but I'm not sure if that's what you're getting at.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: _"ClassToBeTested is a business model class received from REST api."_ It looks like you're trying to test a class belonging to a framework and/or having your one ClassToBeTested serve a role as both a service and a model object. Could you have meant that AAAClass comes from an API instead?

Answer (score 0):

As was already mentioned it is hard to identify what are the objects and what is the context.

But it looks like the classes you'd mentioned are some [DTOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) but at the same time they have some business logic in their getters.

So first of all I would recommend you to extract the business logic to some other place (for instance some service). It should not be present in dto object.

Second. Why `BBBclass`, `CCCclass` and `DDDclass` are inner classes of AAAclass? Can't you make them `static`? Or event more can you extract them into separate classes? It is very important to decrease system complexity.

I think if you solve this issues you'll not need to mock such a complex object anymore.

At the same time remember if you're thinking of adding a constructor/method just for testability it is already a bad sign. It means that your system is becoming complex and abstractions don't work well. Try to rethink your abstractions.